# JWYSIWYG or jHtmlArea within a Jquery Ui Tab

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, wysiwyg

**I am not able to get my jwysiwyg and Jhtmlarea text editors to work within an AJAX loaded Jquery UI Tab**

Both text editors work when loaded normally.

This loads the tabs on the "View Page"

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
 </script>
```

This loads the page via AJAX on the "View Page"

```
<li><a href="/page/edit/">Edit</a></li>
```

This loads the Html Area on the "Edit Page"

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
    $("textarea").htmlarea();
});
</script>
```

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you're injecting the things you're trying to htmlarea-ize into the DOM after the page loads, you have to put your `$("textarea").htmlarea()` inside the callback function of the ajax call.

Comment: Thankyou!

Works perfectly. :) cant stop smiling!

Hope you have a great day